# Django form cache or reload issue

Tags: django, forms

I have a page to insert value to db.
After inserting am loading another page with a drop down listing the db values
But the inserted value is not listing in dropdown

The problem is not with transaction/commit etc. The query to retrieve the data for the drop down in second form is correct.

**Form1(first page)**

```
class Organization(forms.Form):   
    orgList = getOrgUnitList()     

    orgUnit = forms.CharField(label=u'Organization Name',
                            max_length=50,
                            error_messages={'required':'Organization name is required field.'})
    parentOrg= forms.ChoiceField(label=u'Parent Organization',
                       choices=[(u'Select',u'Select')]+orgList,
                       error_messages={'required':'Organization name is required field.'})
```

**Form2(Second page)**

```
class User(forms.Form):    
    orgUnitList = getOrgUnitList()        

    email = forms.EmailField(label=u'Email',
                         max_length=50,
                         error_messages={'required':'Email is required field'})  
    orgUnit = forms.ChoiceField(label=u'Organizational Unit',   
                  choices=orgUnitList,                        
                  error_messages={'required':'Organizational unit is required field'})
```

**Query**

```
def getOrgUnitList():
    orgUnitList = list(OrganizationUnit.objects.values_list
               ('OrgUnitID','OrgUnitName').order_by('OrgUnitName'))
    return orgUnitList
```

but when i tried to bind the choices in view it is working
**working code**
**view**

```
def user()
    template = get_template('AddUser.html')
    form = AddUser()     
    orgUnitList = getOrgUnitList()                    
    del objAdminUIDA
    form.fields['orgUnit'].widget.choices=orgUnitList
    variables = RequestContext(request,{'form':form})
    output = template.render(variables)
    del form
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

But i cant give the dropdown choice in view i want to give choices in form.i need a solution for form2

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Django Form reload data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485677/django-form-reload-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the `orgList` is evaluated in form definition, that's why choices don't change. You should place `getOrgUnitList` in form's `__init__` (or in some other *method*).

Secondly, you don't pass any data to the form, may be you want

```
form = AddUser(request.POST or None)
```